# Can't hear any sound after I plugged my preamp properly

Tags: recording

Good evening.
I started my Cubase adventure today, so I'm new in the business.
I'm using VOX Tonelab ST as a preamp. After I plugged it in and set all properly (at least according to this tutorial:

) I can't hear any sounds though I can see sound waves on a track when I try to record something. My computer seems to take Tonelab as headphones as I see on the volume panel. Could anybody explain what the problem can be?

Comment: hi, this seems like a question better suited for the steinberg forum or tonevox. have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASIO should be capable of sharing the output port with anything else that needs it.

I'd first check your basic setup, see if it matches this [different interface here, but otherwise ought to match]

First thing - make sure your interface is connected [& powered if it needs it] *before* booting the computer.

**Device Menu > Device Setup...**

[image]

[image]

**Device Menu > VST Connections**

[image]

[image]

If everything is OK there, we can investigate further…
Knowing your OS would help too - Mac & Win are different in terms of audio/midi setup.

Comment: Now I have 4 possibilities in VST Connections/Outputs: Tonelab ST 1, Tonelab ST 2, HD Audio Output 1 and HD Audio Output 2. Whichever i pick, doesn't change a thing - still can't hear a sound. My OS is Win 8 64 bit. And, if it matters, i use ASIO4ALL as audio device.

Comment: Doesn't that device come with a cut-down Cubase? If it does, it would be very likely to work at least as well with 'real' ASIO as ASIO4ALL. That would be my first swap, dump ASIO4ALL & get 'real' ASIO going instead. I'd also test the output/speakers, see if you can hear anything when plugging/unplugging the outputs from the Tonelab. Watch your volume if your speakers are self-amped.

Comment: I forgot about one minor thing, wchich I fixed now and all works. Thank you for help.

Comment: . ..which was…?

Comment: @Jozzy please post the answer to your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you see activity in the equalier/mixer/whatever it is but can't hear sound, it could very well be that your sound card is being used by somethign else that is open. Perhaps an internet window, a media player, a video player, spotify... Get back to me on this as I would like to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: I've checked it out - this is not the problem. Even after i switched off everything but Cubase, I still can't hear anything. Maybe this will help: in the section VST Connections/Outputs i can't pick anything but Tonelab as device ports.